# Measuring length through a polyline in QGIS.

Tags: qgis, postgis, measurements

I'm working on a fiber optic project. I want to measure the length through a fiber optic cable (polyline) from a point. Does anyone have an idea to help me?

For example, I'm at the point 082 CTO and want to measure 20 meters from this point through the T081 cable.

[image: fiber optic project]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an indication of where, you can apply a style.  Open up the layer property dialog box of your polyline and:

1. Add a new symbol layer.
2. Change symbol layer type to "simple marker". The default should be a series of red nodes.
3. In the style tree select 'Marker Line'. Select "on First vertex only" and insert you distance in the "Offset along line" text box.
4. If you marker is on the wrong end of the line then change "first vertex" to "last vertex".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual layer (Layer -> Add Layer --> Add Virtual Layer...)

Then import your line layer and your point layer. You must have a common field to join both layers.

Than you can write something like that:

```sql
SELECT
    -- Interpolate a point on a fraction of the line [0,1]
    ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(
        l.geometry,
        -- locate the position of the point as a fraction of the line [0,1]
        ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.geometry, p.geometry) 
            -- add 20 m relative to the length of the line
            + 20.0 /ST_Length(l.geometry)
    ) geometry
FROM
    fiber_line l
JOIN
    fiber_points p ON p.line_name = l.name; -- you need a common attribute
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @thibautg. `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point` returns a point interpolated along a line. It only works with if  the geometry is a linestring. In my case, the geometry is a MULTILINESTRING and I have to use firt `ST_LineMerge`.

Comment: OK did it work with `ST_LineMerge`? Because unfortunately PostGIS's `ST_Dump` function does not exist in Spatialite and the Virtual Layer uses Spatialite functions.

Comment: I don't know if `ST_LineMerge` works, sorry. Finally I chose the option to edit the style, as explained @knightshound.